# nVidia Quadro 2000 Not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on older HP computer with grphic card nVidia Quadro 2000. My main problem is that I try many things but can't install this driver.

First I try with original driver, then have a problem with login. I install GDM and that solve login issue. I get my resolution, and when apply it, my picture become totaly mess. After restart I  can only use monitor resolution 640x480. I try many thing from ubuntu forums and now finaly my computer get stack on login.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: nVidia recommend 375 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I select the Quadro 2000 on [Nvidia’s driver page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) they recommend [the 375-series driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/118290/) which you can install from the `nvidia-375` package. You may also be interested in the `nvidia-settings` package for a more specialised graphics and display settings configuration application.

For more info see [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](/q/61396/175814)